# Android use an imageview to show a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How to? The spinner not showing, but the imageview yes. When i click on the image, then the Spinner showing up.

Comment: ellaborate your requirement exactly !! what you want to do/implement?

Comment: i want to show up the spinner when you click on the imageview!

Answer (score 0):

Set the imageview in a style.

And use that  in spinner layout in .xml file.